# Reimplementing NSBundle loadNibNamed:owner:options: on the Mac

Tags: macos, cocoa

I was reading [a post detailing a technique to implement part of a custom view's interface in Objective-C and part of it in Interface Builder](http://bartlettpublishing.com/site/bartpub/blog/3/entry/327), then be able to add a custom view to another object and set its class to the subclass created beforehand.

On iOS there is a category method in NSBundle called `loadNibNamed:owner:options:`. but unfortunately this does not exist on OS X for some strange reason. How can I perform the equivalent in AppKit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's `[+NSBundle loadNibNamed:owner:]`, just no `options`.